# Convert HHMM String to GMT format in Java

Tags: java, date

I need to convert a String of the form HHMM (in EST or EDT - today) into a GMT timestamp of the form YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS.  So if I get 1512, I want to express 3:12EDT in the GMT time and format: 20110714-20:12:00.  How can I do this?

I have tried the following code and it does not convert at all.

```
    int hour = Integer.parseInt(HHMM.substring(0, 2));
    int min  = Integer.parseInt(HHMM.substring(2, 4));

    Date day = new Date();
    day.setHours(hour);
    day.setMinutes(min);
    day.setSeconds(00); 
    DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    gmtFormat.format(day);

    return day.getYear() + "" + day.getMonth() + "" + 
           day.getDate() + "-" + day.getHours() + ":" + 
           day.getMinutes() + ":" + day.getSeconds();
```

Comment: Just one note, you shouldnt use date.setHours since they are deprecated try using Calendar object.

Comment: `gmt.format(day)` is returning a string - you don't want those results?

Comment: with Calendar you can just cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, hourValue);

Comment: Trying the same thing with the Calendar object I'm still not getting the results I expect.  If I use 0312, I get 18:55:462, and using 0930, I get a time with tomorrow's date

Comment: Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
        day.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        day.add(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
        day.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);        
     
        day.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));        

        return day.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "" + day.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "" + 
               day.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + day.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + 
               day.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + day.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses, I combined a few answers to end up with the following code which correctly converts to GMT and gives me the formatted String I require.

```
private static String convertHHMMtoGMT(String HHMM)
{       
    Calendar day = Calendar.getInstance();
    day.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    day.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
    day.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
    day.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 00);    

    SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    return gmtFormat.format(day.getTime());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit shorter and clearer (IMO) in [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html):

```
public static String printIsoTime(String hhmm)    {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmm");

    // construct datetime from local midnight + parsed hhmm
    DateTime localDateTime = new LocalDate().toDateTime(
        fmt.parseDateTime(hhmm).toLocalTime());

    // convert to UTC and print in ISO format
    return ISODateTimeFormat.dateHourMinuteSecond()
        .print(localDateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC));
}
```

Comment: Folks might as well take the plunge with Joda! JSR-310 isn't going to be included in JDK7, and until it's ready Joda certainly is better than the built-in classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about,

```
    //obtain a formatted string with the year day month information for today
    Date today = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat todaySdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-");
    String todaySdfString = todaySdf.format(today);

    //now concatenate today's info from above with the time info and then parse the whole thing
    SimpleDateFormat edtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mmz");
    Date dt = edtFormat.parse(todaySdfString+"15:12EDT");

    //now GMT
    SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    String fmtDt = gmtFormat.format(dt);
    System.out.println("fmtDt = " + fmtDt);
```

Comment: This code outputs:
dt = Thu Jan 01 02:12:00 EST 1970
fmtDt = 19700101-07:12:00

Comment: Is the time  3:12EDT always for the current day ?

Comment: Closer, it does seem to give the right answer, but in the 12 hour clock (I need 24).  I'm not sure it is safe to assume EDT, as opposed to EST.  Is there a generic way of taking either EST/EDT, changing the hour/min/sec and converting to 24 hour GMT?

Comment: Oh i see. So your input string is itself 24 hour format, then the code will work just use 15:12 instead of 3:12 . About the timezone, where are you getting this time string from? Does it come with the timezone appended? If not, are you able to determine which timezone it is?

Comment: Yes, I will be receiving something in the form "1512".  It does not come with a timezone, but it should be the same timezone as the rest of the system.  The latest edit is giving me 20110713-13:12:00 (yesterday?)

Comment: @Risa let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1488/discussion-between-aldrin-and-risa)

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using Calendar, but the way you have it set up now this should work:

```
Date day = new Date();
day.setHours(3);
day.setMinutes(12);
day.setSeconds(00);

SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd-hh:mm:ss");
gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT") );

Date fmtDay = gmtFormat.format(day);
System.out.println("fmtDay: " + fmtDay);
```